# Linux Solaris - How to bypass zip 2GB file-size limit

Tags: bash

I work on a Solaris (32-bit) platform. Package zip version : 2.3. 
We have a bash script which compress a lot and large XML files. However, we have the following error: File too large & "File size limit exceeded" 
We can not upgrade the kernel or the zip package or change the archive format. 
I would like to know if it's possible with a bash script to generate several archives zip files :
Begin compression.For example, if the archive size reaches 1.8Go, the script starts one second archive ...

if it is possible, can you please, how I can set up ?

Thanks for your help
Best Regard,

Comment: zip 3.0 supports `-s` option to split to several archives. check if your version supports it.

Answer (score 2):

if your zip command recognizes "-" as a special file, then you can zip files and send it to split command:

```
user@solaris> zip -r - /my/file-*.xml | split -b 2000000000
```

then transfer all `x*` files to another machine and concatenate them into single zip file:

```
user@linux$ cat from/solaris/x* > myxmlfiles.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only zipping XML files, it should be safe to [`split`](http://www.unixnote.com/2010/05/solaris-tip-split-large-files.html) them first, zip each file, and then on the other end unzip and concatenate them.